If X and f(X) have zero covariance, what restrictions does this impose on f?
Apologies if this isn't the right place to ask this question! This is my first time!
It is clear that f cannot be an affine transformation of X if f(X) and X are uncorrelated, but this alone would impose only a very weak restriction on the space of functions to which f belongs. Intuitively, for any given f taken from an infinite dimensional function space, it would seem exceedingly unlikely that X and f(X) be uncorrelated. Is there anything more we can say about what properties f must have beyond saying it is non-linear?

Welcome to CV, Martin. Re "exceedingly unlikely:" That might not be a useful way of thinking about it.  You impose a single linear constraint on $f,$ (namely, $\int f(x)(x-E[X])p_X(x),\mathrm dx= 0$), whence in general you are merely requiring $f$ to lie in a codimension-1 subspace of that function space: that's mighty large!

Thank you for leaving a comment so quickly, and apologies for my slow reply. What you have said already definitely helps! I really have very poor knowledge about infinite dimensional spaces, so I don't know how far this analogy takes me, but very loosely all I meant by "exceedingly unlikely" was something akin to taking a random point from a cube in R^3 and having it land on a particular plane. This still feels like a seems like a strong restriction even though that plane is a codimension-1 subspace, but appreciate everything may be different for infinite dimensional function spaces.

Your remarks suggest you conceive of this function space as supporting some kind of probability distribution.  Where does that come from?  What is the motivation or inspiration for that?  Perhaps, if you were to tell us something about your actual statistical problem, we might be able to provide some useful responses.
